# POI - How do I remove a particular String values in Excel?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've been using Apache POI for display  print files .xls format programmatically. The only problem standing in my way,that is i have date format in the following manner in the excel which changed to string format:

screenshot - excel file,

[image]

this above excel image  contains a (') this string

relevant code here,

```
cell = row.createCell((short)0);
cell.setCellValue(form.getAdd2());// Date
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle2);
```

Answer (score 1):

What exact type returns `form.getAdd2()`? I suspect it is a `String` rather than a `Date`. If so you needs converting that `String` to a `Date` before setting the cell value. Then set that `Date` as the cell value.

Using current `apache poi 4.1.2` this can be done using `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` and `java.time.LocalDate` since there is [Cell.setCellValue(java.time.LocalDate value)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue-java.time.LocalDate-) now.

Up to `apache poi 3.17` it can be done using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date`. [Cell.setCellValue(java.util.Date value)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue-java.util.Date-) is the `setCellValue` method used then.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

class CreateExcelSetDateCellValue {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  List<Form> forms = new ArrayList<Form>();
  Form f;
  f = new Form(); f.setAdd2("10-Jan-2020"); forms.add(f);
  f = new Form(); f.setAdd2("1-Jan-2020"); forms.add(f);
  f = new Form(); f.setAdd2("12-Jan-2020"); forms.add(f);
  f = new Form(); f.setAdd2("19-Jan-2020"); forms.add(f);

  DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
  //SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US); // up to apache poi 3.17

  Workbook workbook  = new XSSFWorkbook();
  CellStyle cellStyle2 = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle2.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("d-MMM-yyyy"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  Row row = sheet.createRow(0); 
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("DateString");
  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("Date");


  int r = 1;
  for (Form form : forms) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue(form.getAdd2());// String
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle2);
   cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellValue(LocalDate.parse(form.getAdd2(), dateTimeFormatter));// Date
   //cell.setCellValue(simpleDateFormatter.parse(form.getAdd2()));// Date up to apache poi 3.17
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle2);
   r++;
  }

  sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 15*256);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 15*256);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }

 static class Form {
  private String add2 = "";

  public void setAdd2(String add2) {
   this.add2 = add2;
  }

  public String getAdd2() {
   return this.add2;
  }
 }
}
```

Column `A` contains the dates as `Strings` and shows your issue. Column `B` contains really dates.